# Windows 10 IP Forwarding

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, ip

I am trying to provide Windows 10 with router capabilities(IP Forward). Yes I know I could buy a  router or switch. This setup is for TESTING only.

Found a good resource: http://www.home-network-help.com/ip-forwarding.html

However after setting everything up, I still cannot get to the internet from LAN2(USB). LAN1 can get to internet. My setup:

- Computer 1

  - Lan1 (main connection, can access Internet)

    ```
    IP      192.168.130.47
    Submask 255.255.255.0
    Gateway 192.168.130.1
    ```
  - Lan2 (USB NIC)

    ```
    IP      192.168.140.47
    Submask 255.255.255.0
    Gateway -
    ```
- Computer 2

  - Lan1 (Connected to Lan2 of Computer1)

    ```
    IP      192.168.140.48
    Submask 255.255.255.0
    Gateway 192.168.140.47
    ```

In regedit I have enabled IPEnableRouter. I rebooted my computer.

- I can ping Lan1-Computer2 192.168.140.48 from Lan2-Computer 1 192.168.140.47
- I can ping Lan2-Computer1 192.168.140.47 from Lan2-Computer2 192.168.140.46
- I can ping LAN1-Computer1  192.168.130.47

So LAN1 can contact LAN2 vice versa but not the internet (which gateway is 192.168.130.1)

Any help please?

Comment: Out of curiosity.. why not simply use the Windows 10 Internet Connection sharing? (Control Panel - Network and Internet - Network Connections - right click and Properties on the network you wanted to share - and go into the sharing tab)

Comment: Because that is the obvious answer. Again just testing other options.

Comment: did you mange to get this working?

Comment: *I can ping Lan2-Computer1 192.168.140.47 from Lan2-Computer2 192.168.140.46* You didn't mention `...140.46` anywhere. What's it all about? *I can ping LAN1-Computer1 192.168.130.47* From where can you ping it?

Answer (score 1):

If PC1 can ping PC2 and vice versa, the problem exists in your upstream router, in not having a proper route back to the 192.168.140.0/24 network.

To resolve this, go into your router settings and add a static route as follows :
Network : 192.168.140.0
Mask : 255.255.255.0
Route : 192.168.130.47

Also enable Routing and Remote Access (RRAS) service from services.msc (automatic start).

This should solve your issue.

(You do not need to add any static route on PC1 or PC2, except **IPEnableRouter** set to 1).

Comment: I am upvoting this answer because it is the most correct one so far. In the situation the OP described, PC2 can send packets to the internet router (via PC1), but the router cannot reply to such packets, because it is in subnet `...130.x` and therefore does not know what to do with packets destined for subnet `...140.x`. To let it know that, you have to establish a route to `...140.x` (via `...130.47`) on the internet router.

Answer (score 0):

On Computer 1 make sure the Routing and Remote Access service is enabled and started.  In windows 10 it is disabled by default.

Comment: OP preferred static routing enabled by IPEnableRouter over ICS. NAT through RRAS is only available for Windows Server.

Comment: Personally, I can only ever ping both Computers from each other, for routing Internet I had to use ICS on Windows 10. It wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: @DavidRefoua You can have Windows acting as a router. You don't need ICS for that (ICS is not routing). However, additionally you might have to establish routes on other devices (in this case, the actual internet router) to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the DNS address, that PC1 is using, on PC2. So run the ipconfig command in a command prompt on PC1 and check the DNS address that is provided by your PC1 internet interface. I personally don't need to add a static route, as hinted here. Simply add that same DNS address from PC1, in PC2 - as the DNS address.

Here's my setup:

1. Activate IP Forwarding.
2. Activate Remote Access (actually this is enabled by default, I think, but check anyway).
3. Set static IPv4 addressed on your LAN, for your two PCs (more detail below).
4. Share your internet interface on PC1 with your LAN.

So in more detail:

- When I share my phone interface (that connects my PC to the internet), Windows sets my PC1 LAN interface address to 192.168.137.1. That's done.
- Now, on PC2, I set the LAN interface address to 192.168.137.2 and the default gateway to PC1 which is 192.168.137.1. And I also need to set the DNS to 192.168.42.129 - this is the DNS that PC1 is using and is provided by my phone network interface.

You may need to reboot to have it working.

Comment: *Activate Remote Access* This is not needed. Remote access is not routing (although the service has a very misleading name). *Share your internet interface on PC1 with your LAN.* This is not necessary for pure routing. You can have Windows acting as a router; but you might get unexpected results as long as you haven't re-configured other network components. Notably, you probably must establish a route to PC2 in the actual internet router.